# Kaminari error - undefined method `<' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kaminari

I'm facing a problem with Kaminari paginate. This is the code:

```
<% table %>
...
<% @usuarios.each do |usuario| %>
<tbody id="usuarios">
    <%= render partial: "admin/redes/redes/usuarios_rede", locals: {usuario_rede: usuario} %>
</tbody>
<% end %>
</table>
<div id="paginator-usuarios">
<%= paginate @usuarios, :params => { :action => "usuarios_page" }, :remote => true %>
</div>
```

@usuarios isn't null, I already checked. I think the problem is on paginate, but I don't understand why.
Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: you have a nil object where you shouldn't. You need to provide more code. the relevant controller for start.

Comment: With the code that you provided, it appears that you have one too many `<% end %>`